# Highcharts Realtime Multi-series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having trouble getting a realtime chart working. The data will arrive in realtime, there is no historical data to start with. I'd like to be able to show the last 10 minutes in the chart window as time ticks the chart along as the data comes in. The data for each series will arrive at a random time. I've done this jsFiddle.

How can I show the last 10 minutes and tick along (currently just shows last point/single data?

[Real-time Chart jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8docefLy/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
      marginRight: 10,
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var series1 = this.addSeries({
            name: "Random 1",
            data: [[(new Date()).getTime(), 5000]]
          });
          var series2 = this.addSeries({
            name: "Random 2",
            data: [[(new Date()).getTime(), 5000]]
          });
          (function loop() {
            var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 500;
            setTimeout(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime();
              var y1 = 5000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
              var y2 = 5000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
              //console.log(x + ', ' + y);
              series1.addPoint([x, y1], true, true);
              series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
              loop();
            }, rand);
          }());
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: For every load, you are adding new series. You are not adding points to your existing series. In my understanding this will replace previous series, and therefore there will be no historic points to show, only the current points. If you add points to a series you can use `tickPlacement`, `tickInterval`, `tickAmount`, or one of the other parameters on the `xAxis` to show or hide parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setExtremes` function instead of `shift` option in `addPoint`. This line of code:

```
xAxis.setExtremes(Math.max(series1.points[0].x, x - 10 * 1000 /*10s*/));
```

will cause the following behavior of the `xAxis`:

If the first point of the first series has the `x` value within the last 10 seconds (I used seconds instead of minutes to see the effect sooner) then it becomes the low extreme. Otherwise it applies the latest point's x value decreased by 10 seconds as the low extreme.

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/66kyh13k/

Notice that I disabled redrawing in both `addPoint` calls. The redraw happens on `setExtremes` and there's no need to perform it before.

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#addPoint
- http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis.html#setExtremes